# XAML Daily Calendar Control (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, calendar, custom-controls, windows-phone-8.1

I am looking for a daily calendar control written in XAML for the use in a Windows Phone 8.1 app. Everything I found so far are calendars with monthly or weekly views, which I am not interested in.

It would be nice if it had some kind of timeline (like in the example below) and supported the displaying of events with custom start and end times (at least).

By daily, I mean that only one calendar day and it's corresponding events is shown at a time, like so (Windows Phone default calendar):
[image: Windows Phone default calendar - Daily view]

Comment: See this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216901/windows-phone-8-1-daily-calendar-and-issue

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt Control and no third party controls(AFAIK).

I have made enough searches and finally implemented on my Own.

Some general Ideas are:

```
 <ListView>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <ItemsControl>
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">   
                  <Rectangle/>
              </Stackpanel>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Make you viewmodel to fit into this structure .I used this way and achieved it perfecly.